# Find all maximum substrings of digits

Tags: python, for-loop, line

I need to write a program to find all maximum substrings of digits.
Return only these substrings separated by spaces in their order.
Do not use regular expressions, just the simplest capabilities of programming language

> 34234 34  dfd gfd 5

> 34535

> fsdflskfjsdflk

> fsdkfj sdf34fdfd

> 1,3

> 1/5

should give this:

> 34234 34 5

> 34535

> 34

> 1 3

> 1 5

but in last two outputs i get 13 and 15 instead of 1 3 and 1 5. So if there is digit like x.x or x,x or x/x it should give digits and space between them. Any idea how to reach that? My code is below

```
for linia in plik:
linia = linia.strip("\n")

i=0
current_string = ''

for i in range(len(linia)):
    if linia[i].isdigit() or (linia[i-1].isdigit() and linia[i].isspace()) :
        current_string+=linia[i]
        i+=1

if(current_string!=''):
    print(current_string)
```

Comment: "I need to write a program which returns only _these_ substrings" - which substrings? Just ones that contain exclusively digits?

Comment: @SimonN Edited. I need to write a program to find all maximum substrings of digits.
Return only these substrings separated by spaces in their order.
Do not use regular expressions, just the simplest capabilities of programming language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag to check for non-digit gaps. Write a space for each gap.

Try this code:

```
plik = [
"34234 34 dfd gfd 5",
"34535",
"fsdflskfjsdflk",
"fsdkfj sdf34fdfd",
"1,3",
"1/5"]

for linia in plik:
    linia = linia.strip("\n")

    i=0
    current_string = ''

    gap = False
    for i in range(len(linia)):
        if linia[i].isdigit() :
            if gap : current_string+=' '
            current_string+=linia[i]
            i+=1
            gap = False
        elif len(current_string):
            gap = True

    if(current_string!=''):
        print(current_string)
```

Output

```
34234 34 5
34535
34
1 3
1 5
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I have one question - what for does elif len(current_string) stand for?

Comment: It checks the output string so gaps are not put at the start of the string. You can change it to `else:` to see the difference. '34' will become ' 34' (leading space)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here. The most obvious one being that your code doesn't contain any way to add a space where one doesn't exist in the original string. You want `1/5` to give `1 5` but this is impossible as you never attempt to write a space character.

By using indexing you've also introduced a possible bug whereby `linea[i-1]` will be `linea[-1]` when `i=0` which means the last letter of the string.

Using a simple for loop, a list and the join method provides a convenient and readable option:

```
plik = [
"34234 34 dfd gfd 5",
"34535",
"fsdflskfjsdflk",
"fsdkfj sdf34fdfd",
"1,3",
"1/5"]

for linia in plik:
    linia = linia.strip("\n")

    current_string = ''
    output = []

    for x in linia:
        if x.isdigit():
            current_string += x
        elif not current_string == '':
            output.append(current_string)
            current_string = ''

    if not current_string == '':
        output.append(current_string)

    if output:
        print(' '.join(output))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It works almost fine. In my example there is line: fsdkfj sdf34fdfd
With that the programme should give 34 on this line, but gives none.

Comment: I can't reproduce that - I get 34 when I run it with the string you mention.

Comment: I can see the problem now. On the output I need no blank lines, for example when there are only letters in line or line is blank it gives blank line in the output, so when i tried 
if current_string!='':
 print(' '.join(output)
it deleted 34
Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: The current_string variable is only meaningful inside the loop so trying to use it in that way could give odd results and certainly won't do what you wanted. I'll edit the answer.